# Using html5 localstorage can I find the index corresponding to a key value

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

```
window.localStorage.setItem("Georgia","Atlanta") 
var x=window.localStorage.getItem("Georgia")
```

I have a list of 50 states and the largest city stored in localstorage.
Using the code above I can easily retrieve that Atlanta is the largest city for "Georgia".
Is there an easy way to do a reverse lookup and search for "Atlanta" and get "Georgia"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Local Storage is a simple map from key to value, so no. There is no method to look up the key for a value, or more accurately, the key**s** because there may be more than one.

You could additionally store a reverse table of city->state to accomplish this:

```
// Georgia's largest city is Atlanta
window.localStorage.setItem("Georgia", "Atlanta") 

// What is Georgia's largest city?
var x=window.localStorage.getItem("Georgia") // returns Atlanta

// Atlanta is in Georgia
window.localStorage.setItem("Atlanta", "Georgia")

// What state does Atlanta belong to?
var y=window.localStorage.getItem("Atlanta") // returns Georgia
```

So now `setItem()` means "there is a relationship between X and Y" and `getItem()` means "is there a / what is the relationship between X and Y?"

Ideally you'd have these in two different tables to separate out what type of relationship you're talking about (i.e., state->city and city->state) but you should be okay in this simple case.